# formating time and date; drop time component

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a DOB column that contains the date and time.  The time portion is always zeroes and I want to get rid of that. Maybe an `alter table` statement? Here is an example

```
DOB

1998-02-23 00:00:00.000

1987-02-15 00:00:00.000
```

I want

```
DOB 

1998-02-23

1987-02-15
```

Comment: Either cast the column as a `date`, or alter the column to use the `date` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Storing as `date` takes only 3 bytes per row rather than 8 for `datetime`. As an `ALTER TABLE` statement

```
CREATE TABLE #T(DOB DATETIME NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('19980223 00:00:00.000'), 
                      ('19870215 00:00:00.000')

ALTER TABLE #T ALTER COLUMN DOB DATE  NOT NULL

SELECT *
FROM #T

DROP TABLE #T
```